# ERROR in CREATE VIEW

Tags: sql, ms-access

I tried to create a new view in my MS Access database so I can select better from it but I wonder what's happening here.

```
CREATE VIEW new 
AS 
  SELECT msthread.id, 
         msthread.threadname, 
         Count(msthread.threadname) AS TotalPost, 
         threadcategory 
  FROM   msthread 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN msposts 
                      ON msthread.threadname = msposts.threadname 
  GROUP  BY msthread.id, 
            msthread.threadname, 
            msthread.threadcategory
```

Access gives me this error message when I try to execute that statement.

> Syntax error in create table statement

Is there specific problems in creating view with JOINs? I'm trying to access 2 tables.

Comment: **WHAT'S THE ERROR?!** Also, what DBMS are you using? Just guessing, but if there's `threadcategory` in both tables, then you're missing an alias.

Comment: @kenlz, I don't see anything wrong in your query except that you are not referencing `threadcategory` column with `msthread`. I mean it should be `msthread.threadcategory`

Comment: **WHERE'S THE REST OF THE ERROR MESSAGE?!** You still haven't told us what DBMS you're using.

Comment: `new` is a likely a keyword and can't be used without delimiting with brackets.  Is the name of the view actually `new`?

Comment: Googling that error message returns threads about both Access and Oracle. Which one, if either, are you using?

Comment: Works in [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d019f), [SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d019f), [Postgresql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d019f), [Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d019f) and [SQLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d019f). There is something you are not telling us!!

Comment: @MartinSmith That would probably explain it since Access does not support the `CREATE VIEW` syntax.

Comment: @GarethD - Any idea on the syntax to create a saved query in Access?

Comment: @MartinSmith As far as I am aware you can't do it using SQL alone, you have to actually save the query (using File > Save) then reference the saved name when it needs to be used, although I could be wrong. Best person I know of for Access questions on here is [Hansup](http://stackoverflow.com/users/77335/hansup), although I'd hazard a guess he won't see the question before it is closed.

Comment: I  am using Access guys, sorry to be a disappointment in this question :(

Answer (score 2):

`CREATE VIEW` was introduced with Jet 4 in Access 2000.  But you must execute the statement from ADO/OleDb.  If executed from DAO, it triggers error 3290, *"Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement"*,  which is more confusing than helpful.

Also `CREATE VIEW` can only create simple `SELECT` queries.  Use `CREATE PROCEDURE` for any which `CREATE VIEW` can't handle.

But `CREATE VIEW` should handle yours.  I used a string variable to hold the DDL statement below, and then executed it from `CurrentProject.Connection` in an Access session:

```vb
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
```

That worked because `CurrentProject.Connection` is an ADO object.  If you will be doing this from outside Access, use an OleDb connection.

Notice I made a few changes to your query.  Most were minor.  But I think the query name change may be important.  `New` is a reserved word so I chose `qryNew` instead.  Reserved words as object names seem especially troublesome in queries run from ADO/OleDb.

```sql
CREATE VIEW qryNew
AS
SELECT
    mst.id,
    mst.threadname,
    mst.threadcategory,
    Count(mst.threadname) AS TotalPost
FROM
    msthread AS mst
    LEFT JOIN msposts AS msp
    ON mst.threadname = msp.threadname
GROUP BY
    mst.id,
    mst.threadname,
    mst.threadcategory;
```

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb here without the error message but my assumption is that you need an alias in front of your non-aliased column.

You may also have a problem titling the view as new. This is a problem with using a generic name for a view or table.  Try giving it a distinct name that matters. I'll use msThreadPosts as an example.

```
CREATE VIEW msThreadPosts 
AS 
  SELECT msthread.id, 
         msthread.threadname, 
         Count(msthread.threadname) AS TotalPost, 
         msposts.threadcategory --Not sure if you want msposts or msthread just pick one
  FROM   msthread 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN msposts 
                      ON msthread.threadname = msposts.threadname 
  GROUP  BY msthread.id, 
            msthread.threadname, 
            msthread.threadcategory
```

As long as we are looking at this query lets fix some other things that are being done in a silly way.

Lets start off with aliasing. If you alias a column you can very easily make your query easy to understand and read to anyone who is inclined to read it.

```
CREATE VIEW msThreadPosts 
AS 
  SELECT mt.id, 
         mt.threadname, 
         Count(mt.threadname) AS TotalPost, 
         mp.threadcategory 
  FROM   mtas mt
         LEFT OUTER JOIN msposts mp
                      ON mt.threadname = mp.threadname 
  GROUP  BY mt.id, 
            mt.threadname, 
            mt.threadcategory
```

There now doesn't that look better.

The next thing to look as if your column names. msthread has an id column. That column name is incredibly generic. This can cause problems when a column isn't aliased and an id exists in mulitple places or there are muliple id columns. Now if we change that column name to `msthreadID` it makes things much clearer. The goal is to design your tables in a way that anyone working on your database can imidiatley tell what a column is doing.

The next thing to look at is your join. Why are you joining on thread name? `threadname` is likely a character string and therefore not terribly efficient for joins. if `msthread` as an id column and needs to be joined to `msposts` then shouldn't `msposts` also have that id column to match up on to make joins more efficient?