# Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement when i am creating procedure

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

I am having really strange problem. I have just written a code  that should create procedure and then execute it. But it is giving me this error:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access] Syntax error in statement CREATE TABLE 
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at mDat.procedures.createProcedure(procedures.java:25)
    at mDat.procedures.main(procedures.java:14)
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class procedures { 
    static Connection con;
    static String procedure;
    public static void main(String[]args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        getConnection("jdbc:odbc:TestDatabaze");
        createProcedure();
        executeProcedure();
        con.close();
    }
    static void getConnection(String connection) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(connection);
    }
    public static void createProcedure() throws SQLException{
        procedure="CREATE PROCEDURE newest_user AS SELECT Firstname, Lastname FROM members WHERE ID= max(ID)";
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        s.execute(procedure);
        s.close();
    }
    public static void executeProcedure() throws SQLException{
        CallableStatement cs=con.prepareCall("{CALL newest_user}");
        String fn=cs.getString(1);
        String ln=cs.getString(2);
        System.out.println("Name of the newest user in database is "+fn+" "+ln);
    }
}
```

I really have no idea why it is giving me that error, becouse there is no code for creating table. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no `CREATE TABLE` statement in the code you posted (and the use of the `max()` function in `SELECT` statement is invalid as well - unless MS-Access has a very strange SQL dialect)

Comment: I believe you mean CREATE TABLE newest_user and not CREATE_PROCEDURE newest_user ?

Comment: That `SELECT` statement will not work in Access regardless of how you create it.  If you did have a `SELECT` which Access accepts, you could then use `CREATE VIEW` instead of `CREATE PROCEDURE`.  However, I'm unsure whether that can even be done from an ODBC connection.

Comment: And the error message does complain about `CREATE TABLE`, which is more confusing than helpful.  See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844491/error-in-create-view/20882993#20882993).